# FB.api async issue

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql

I have a website, which has to check if user has liked my facebook fan page. And I write a `JS function` with `FB.api()` and `FQL`

```
function checkIsLike(){
    var liked = false;
    if(FB_USER_ID){ //the facebook userID
        FB.api({
            method: 'fql.query',
            query: 'SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE uid='+FB_USER_ID+' AND page_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        },function(response){
            console.log(response);
            if(response){
                return  true;
            }else{
                return  false
            }
        });
    }else{
        return  false;
    }
}
```

And when I simply check if the function works

```
console.log(checkIsLike());
```

It always give me **undefined** , and found that the `FB.api()` runs a async function and so it doesn't return anything once the console.log() is called.

How can I disable the `async` attribute of the `FB.api()` call?

Answer (score 0):

You can´t (and shouldn´t) disable this, you have to deal with the asynchronous code. For example, you can just call another function in the response function. Or you can add a parameter with a callback:

```
function checkIsLike(callback) {
    ...
    function(response) {
        callback(response);
    ...
}

checkIsLike(function (response) {

});
```

Although in this case i would just use a second function instead of the callback parameter with an anonymous function. Or - if you just need to trace the response - put the "console.log" in the callback function of the API call.